# Design review/criticism of secure master-workers system

Tags: tls, audit

I am designing a system which will have one main process/service (**master**) which can potentially offload part of it's work to N number of external remote processes (**workers**). I want the worker deployment to be simple, yet the the master-workers communication to be secure, with authentication and authorization on both sides. This might operate in isolated environment, so dependency on any external services isn't permitted.

Below is the design I came up with and I would like to understand whether it's sound or not. I am looking for criticism of the design both for reasons why it's not secure or why it's overcomplicated. I am not security expert, so I might be missing some major point.

1. The user installs the worker using public/generic repo.
2. In post-install init the worker performs this:

   1. Generates it's own unique ID. The ID will be used as base of the CA, server and client DNs in the certs below.
   2. Generates self-signed CA certificate.
   3. Generates server key-pair and certificate signed by CA from above.
   4. Generates client key-pair and certificate signed by CA from above.
   5. Places the CA certificate, client certificate, client key and it's ID into base-64 encoded *connection token*.
   6. The private key belonging to the CA is discarded.
3. The worker starts it's service on defined port, serving the server
   certificate, requiring client certs for connection, using the
   CA-certificate to verify the client certs and checking client DNs.
4. The user transfers the *connection token* to the master, where he
   initiates the worker registration. He provides the worker
   hostname/ip and the connection token.
5. The master connects to
   the worker using the client cert from the token and using the CA
   cert from the token to verify the server identity. The actual worker
   hostname/ip is not used, instead it verifies the alternative
   identity derived from the worker ID to match the one provided in the
   server's cert.

Providing that the *connection token* distribution is trusted (e.g. the installing user does not provide spoofed *token* when registering worker), this should ensure that the worker only accepts connections from the master to which the token was presented. At the same time, the master can be sure it's connecting to the worker who initially generated the *token*.

There is no cert-renewal process build in. The workers are supposed to be state-less and disposable, so if there is a need for regular cert rotation, it could simply be achieved by killing the worker and re-installing with new identity. I could imagine that the worker might not drop it's CA private key in (2.6) and do some cert-reissuing logic, but I am not sure that would improve security while definitely increasing complexity.

Comment: Related inspiration for you; If you look at bitbucket.org's pipelines, they offer a "run your own workers" where you get a docker command to copy where the worker then dial home (i guess some of the command is their key, and that they have the master cert built in. but I'd recommend you look at that for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks @JoSSte, the bitbucket's runners are slightly different in that they are reaching public service with trusted cert, so the only thing they need to pass to the agent is the token to authenticate. Though I guess it points to possible simplification in my case that I could avoid the client cert use and only use some simple secret instead of it.

Comment: When it comes to maintaining and regaining an overview of an application "simple" wins. I sometoimes end up overthinking solutions, take a break, and go back in with the "what is it i want to accomplish" approach - often that gives a better overview